# How to display total in Donut hole in Ext js Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

**How** to display total in donut hole of my pie chart ?

**Here** is my example code

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        fields: ['name', 'data'],
        data: [{
            'name': 'metric one',
            'data': 10
        }, {
            'name': 'metric two',
            'data': 7
        }, {
            'name': 'metric three',
            'data': 5
        }, {
            'name': 'metric four',
            'data': 2
        }, {
            'name': 'metric five',
            'data': 27
        }]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 500,
        height: 350,
        animate: true,
        store: store,
        theme: 'Base:gradients',
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            angleField: 'data',
            showInLegend: true,
            donut: 40,
            tips: {
                trackMouse: true,
                width: 140,
                height: 28,
                renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                    // calculate and display percentage on hover
                    var total = 0;
                    store.each(function(rec) {
                        total += rec.get('data');
                    });
                    this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + Math.round(storeItem.get('data') / total * 100) + '%');
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

**Here** is my output

[image]

**How** to display the total in donut hole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a text sprite to your chart using the items config:

```
Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 350,
    animate: true,
    store: store,
    theme: 'Base:gradients',
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        angleField: 'data',
        showInLegend: true,
        donut:40,
        tips: {
            trackMouse: true,
            width: 140,
            height: 28,
            renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                // calculate and display percentage on hover
                var total = 0;
                store.each(function(rec) {
                    total += rec.get('data');
                });
                this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + Math.round(storeItem.get('data') / total * 100) + '%');
            }
        }
    }],
    items : [{
        type: "text",
        text: store.sum('data'),
        fill: "green",
        font: "36px monospace",
        x: 227,
        y: 170
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response... I have a doubt like if we give x and y positions directly . it will work in all types of screen resolutions?

Comment: Humm, good question... usually the browser is pretty good at rendering things are they supposed to. Because it will work with the proportions of the elements you are rendering, but I'm not sure how this would react with retina displays for instance. Run tests and if you run into some issues post another question here and I'll take a look